# Trying to assign a number and have it increment, but also save the last number used after program is closed

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign a number to a person in my code. I am creating a program that stores competitor information for competition. I am storing the competitor information in a .txt file in order to keep it when the program is closed. I want to be able to assign a competitor number to each competitor and have them increment. They must also save the last number used in the program and save each specific number to each competitor. This is so that after I have entered a few competitors and close the program then the competitor number given to the next competitor I enter information for, when I restart the program, isn't 1 again. I am currently manually inputting a competitor number. -The following pieces of code are extracts as the program is very long- I have tried things like regularly incrementing the value but this does not save. Thanks

```
private static void writeToCompetitorFile()
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("../../CompetitorFile.txt", true))
    {
        writer.Write(CompetitorName + ",");
        writer.Write(CompetitorNumber + ",");
        writer.Write(CompetitorClimbOne + ",");
        writer.Write(CompetitorClimbTwo + ",");
        writer.Write(CompetitorClimbThree + ",");
        writer.WriteLine(CompetitorReactionTime);
        //This allows the data input by the user to be saved to a .txt file
    }
}
```

---

```
private static void SortData1()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("COMPETITOR DETAILS\n");
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    String[] reportLine = new String[6];
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Competitor Number", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Climb One Time", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Climb Two Time", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Climb Three Time", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Reaction Time", typeof(double));
    StreamReader srcnRdr = new StreamReader("../../CompetitorFile.txt");
    String Data = srcnRdr.ReadLine();
    //This adds all input information into the table to be displayed

    while (Data != null)
    {
        reportLine = Data.Split(',');
        table.Rows.Add(reportLine[0], reportLine[1], reportLine[2], reportLine[3], reportLine[4], reportLine[5]);
        Data = srcnRdr.ReadLine();
    }
    srcnRdr.Close();

    table.DefaultView.Sort = "Name";
    DataView viewtable = table.DefaultView;
    Console.WriteLine("=== Sorted by Name ===");
    for (int i = 0; i < viewtable.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}",
                viewtable[i][0],
                viewtable[i][1],
                viewtable[i][2],
                viewtable[i][3],
                viewtable[i][4],
                viewtable[i][5]);
        //This allows the user to view competitor data sorted by names in alphabetical order if they press '2' on the menu page
    }
}
```

---

Comment: You don´t save the new number to your file anywehere. How do you expect the file to change when you don´t make it do so.

Comment: Given that you're storing your data in a DataTable, the simplest way to save and load it is via the built in ReadXml and WriteXml methods of a datatable - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.readxml?view=netframework-4.7.2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Charlie as you have already read the data into the datatable, so just sort that by "Competitor Number" and pick the last number and increment that by 1.

Please let me know if I answered your question.

Comment: I am trying to do this but cannot successfully save the competitor number assigned to the last competitor whose details have been entered. It seems like that could work but saving the last value entered is what is causing me trouble. Thanks for the help so far though i'll keep working with it!

Comment: In the code i am currently using I assign competitor number to equal zero so that the first competitor gets a number of 1 when i do competitornumber = competitor number + 1. However the issue i am still having is setting competitor number to 1 automatically after 1 competitors details have been entered. If it works how i want it to the program will remember what the last competitors number was and add one to it when another competitors details are to be entered and assign them this new incremented number,

Comment: I have now gotten it working by assigning the value outside of that are of code and the incrementing it inside the area of code. I have made it able to save and it works perfectly! Thanks for the help!